# Customizing error messages in sharepoint list forms

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010

i am having three require field coloumns in sharepoint list .when i try to add/edit item in newform.aspx/editform.aspx .. i'm getting error message as 'you must specify the value for required field' for all the three coloumn.

How can i customize the require field error messages in Newform.aspx/Editform.aspx..?

Thanks in advance ...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Two Steps to proceed the custom validation for the required field used in SharePoint List item:

1. Go to List Settings -> Validation Settings, Enter the formula to validate the required column in Formula box and Custom Error message in User Message box for particular column.
2. Go to List Settings -> Choose your required column under Columns section and expand the Custom Validation and edit the formula, error message for that column.  Click Save.

It will works.....